# android:minHeight not working in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am having the following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/top" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:minHeight="300px">
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ff0000"
    android:minHeight="290px">
</WebView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am loading the sample HTML file, the height of the page is 150px. After loading the page, the webview's background is filled with red color only for 150px. But I am setting android:minHeight attribute to 290px.