# Why does minHeight attribute not work in WebView Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview, view-hierarchy

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791414/androidminheight-not-working-in-webview), but it has no solution.

I have a `WebView`. I want to set minimum height to the `WebView` using `minHeight` attribute, but it doesn't work. The same attribute works for Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.anshul.webview.WebActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="400dp"></WebView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="150dp"
    android:text="This is a Button. It's minHeight is set to 150 dp and it works !!"/>
```

Clearly from the below image, the WebView is not supporting the `minHeight` attribute. Does anybody knows a solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: in which android version you have this issue?

Comment: I tried it on Android 25 and faced this issue. But I think it is not related to Android version.

Comment: there were some issues about webview in pre kit kat versions. so i asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's understand how other view's use `android:minHeight` attribute. Let's take `Spinner` for example. In [`AbsSpinner#onMeasure()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java#L227) code we see following chunk of code:

```
...
preferredHeight = Math.max(preferredHeight, getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, getSuggestedMinimumWidth());

heightSize = resolveSizeAndState(preferredHeight, heightMeasureSpec, 0);
widthSize = resolveSizeAndState(preferredWidth, widthMeasureSpec, 30);

setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
...
```

So, [`getSuggestedMinimumHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getSuggestedMinimumHeight()) should be regarded when computing preferred height.

Now, let's see how `WebView` is being measured.

- `WebView#onMeasure()` [delegates the job to](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java#L2625) `WebViewChromium#onMeasure()`
- `WebViewChromium#onMeasure()` [delegates the job to](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/webview/+/android-4.4_r1.1/chromium/java/com/android/webview/chromium/WebViewChromium.java#1900) `AwContents#onMeasure()`
- `AwContents#onMeasure()` [delegates the job to](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview/blob/master/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContents.java#L480) `AwLayoutSizer#onMeasure`

[`AwLayoutSizer`](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview/blob/master/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwLayoutSizer.java) is the last component that is responsible for measuring `WebView` and [we can clearly see](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview/blob/master/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwLayoutSizer.java#L139), that its `onMeasure()` does not respect `getSuggestedMinimumHeight()` value.

I'm not sure whether this is an intended behavior or no. Nevertheless, I cannot find [enough seams](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java#L2336) to somehow affect that measurement process. [Here's](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebView.java#L2331) the chuck of code in `WebView` class, where the object that eventually would return `WebViewChromium` (the first step in abovementioned order) is initialized.

```
    private void ensureProviderCreated() {
        checkThread();
        if (mProvider == null) {
            // As this can get called during the base class constructor chain, pass the minimum
            // number of dependencies here; the rest are deferred to init().
            mProvider = getFactory().createWebView(this, new PrivateAccess());
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is not something that can be easily customized/changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><body bgcolor=\"#E6E6FA\"> hehehe </body></html>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        android:text="This is a Button. It's minHeight is set to 150 dp and it works !!"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You should take into account [warnings](http://i.imgur.com/v1OfFzl.png), that lint gives.

Comment: We can take it by code.
define the height for LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think webview dimensions work more according to content view port properties...

Check https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Viewport

The viewport is the area in which your web page is drawn. Although the viewport's total visible area matches the size of the screen when zoomed all the way out, the viewport has its own pixel dimensions that it makes available to a web page. For example, although a device screen might have physical a width of 480 pixels, the viewport can have a width of 800 pixels. This allows a web page designed at 800 pixels wide to be completely visible on the screen when the viewport scale is 1.0. Most web browsers on Android (including Chrome) set the viewport to a large size by default (known as "wide viewport mode" at about 980px wide). Many browsers also zoom out as far as possible, by default, to show the full viewport width (known as "overview mode").

Answer (score -1):

use constraint layout .that will help to resolve all  these types of errors and very easy to use.

if your android studio version is below 2.3.1 then add this dependency.

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'
```